# Filling a region defined by a reduce command

Tags: differential-equations

I'd like to shade the region defined in the xy-plane produced by this code:

```
In[305]:= Reduce[-x^4 + x^2 (x + y)^2 > 0, x]

Out[305]= (y < 0 && (x < 0 || 0 < x < -(y/2))) || (y > 
    0 && (-(y/2) < x < 0 || x > 0))
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
epxr = -x^4 + x^2 (x + y)^2 > 0;
reg = Reduce[expr, x]; 

RegionPlot[reg, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
(* or RegionPlot[expr, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}] *)
```

[image]

or

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, reg], Axes -> False , PlotPoints -> 100]
(* same picture -- almost *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sol = Reduce[-x^4 + x^2 (x + y)^2 > 0, x]
```

> (y < 0 && (x < 0 || 0 < x < -(y/2))) || (y > 
>       0 && (-(y/2) < x < 0 || x > 0))

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[sol, {x, y}]]
```

[image]